# Finding a reduction formula for $\int x^ne^x dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, self-learning

> For integers $n \geq 0$, let
>   $$I_n = \int x^ne^x dx$$
>   Find a reduction formula for $I_n$ and then calculate $I_3$

For this question, I can find out $I_3$, but I have no idea how to find the reduction formula. Please advise me.

Comment: Have you tried integration by parts?

Comment: You get  a recurrence relation  by using integration by parts.

Comment: As an interesting aside, see [Gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function). :-)

Answer (score 3):

If we use integration by parts as suggested, setting $u = x^n$ and $dv = e^x dx$, we get
$$I_n = \int x^n e^x dx = x^n e^x - \int nx^{n-1}e^x dx = x^ne^x-nI_{n-1}$$
Thus we have our reduction formula
$$I_n = x^ne^x - nI_{n-1}$$
And since $I_0 = e^x+C$, we have
$$I_1 = xe^x-e^x + C$$
$$I_2 = x^2e^x - 2xe^x + 2e^x+C$$
$$I_3=x^3e^x-3x^2e^x+6xe^x-6e^x+C$$

Comment: Great explanation. ;)