# Closed Form Expression for $\int_{0}^{1}x^n\sin(2\pi ax)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Is it possible to find general form of:
$$I_n(a)=\int_{0}^{1}x^n\sin(2\pi ax)dx$$
where $a\in \text{I}$.

Here is example for first few cases:
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1}\sin\left(2\pi ax\right)dx&=0\\
\int_{0}^{1}x\sin\left(2\pi ax\right)dx&=-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\left(\pi a\right)^{1}}\\
\int_{0}^{1}x^{2}\sin\left(2\pi ax\right)dx&=-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\left(\pi a\right)^{1}}\\
\int_{0}^{1}x^{3}\sin\left(2\pi ax\right)dx&=\frac{3}{4}\frac{1}{\left(\pi a\right)^{3}}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\left(\pi a\right)^{1}}\\
\int_{0}^{1}x^{4}\sin\left(2\pi ax\right)dx&=-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\left(\pi a\right)^{1}}+\frac{3}{2}\frac{1}{\left(\pi a\right)^{3}}-\frac{3}{4}\frac{1}{\left(\pi a\right)^{5}}\\
\int_{0}^{1}x^{5}\sin\left(2\pi ax\right)dx&=-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\left(\pi a\right)^{1}}+\frac{5}{2}\frac{1}{\left(\pi a\right)^{3}}-\frac{15}{4}\frac{1}{\left(\pi a\right)^{5}}\\
\int_{0}^{1}x^{6}\sin\left(2\pi ax\right)dx&=-\frac{45}{4}\frac{1}{\left(\pi a\right)^{5}}+\frac{15}{4}\frac{1}{\left(\pi a\right)^{3}}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\left(\pi a\right)^1}
\end{align}
$$

I used series Expansion for $\sin(x)$ and arrived at this expression:
$$I_n(a)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\left(-1\right)^{k}\frac{\left(2\pi a\right)^{1+2k}}{\left(2k+2+n\right)\left(2k+1\right)!}\right)$$

But in this expression we cannot really make use of the fact that $a$ is an Integer as,
$$\cos(2\pi a)=1$$
$$\sin(2\pi a)=0$$

Is it possible to find closed form for this?

EDIT:

I will add some Background on why I need this,

This came upon as part of a Bigger Generalization Problem.
$$\int_{0}^{1}x^m\lfloor tx\rfloor^ndx$$
for $m,n\in I_{x\geq0}$

Here is an example:
$$\int_{0}^{1}x^{2}{\lfloor tx\rfloor}^{2}dx=\frac{t^{2}}{5}+\frac{1}{45t^{2}}-\frac{t}{4}+\frac{1}{12t}-\frac{1}{18}$$

Comment: What type of closed form do you want?

Comment: Take $\sin(\alpha x)=\frac{e^{i\alpha x}-e^{-i\alpha x}}{2i}$ and apply the [power reduction formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/689346/finding-a-reduction-formula-for-int-xnex-dx) (i.e. integrate by parts)

Comment: @TymaGaidash As I have shown in the examples, I think there should be a simpler form which uses the fact that $\cos(2\pi a)=1$ and $\sin(2\pi a)=0$.

Comment: @user170231 Right! That does give us
$$I_n(a)=-\frac{1}{2\pi a}-\frac{n\left(n-1\right)}{4\pi^{2}a^{2}}I_{n-2}(a)$$
But I am still hoping for a better form.

Comment: assuming $a$ and $n$ are positive integers, then$$
\int_0^1{x^n\sin \left( 2\pi ax \right)}\mathrm{d}x=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}{\frac{\left( n \right) _{2k}\left( -1 \right) ^{k+1}}{\left( 2\pi a \right) ^{2k+1}}}
$$
is this closed enough?

Comment: @oO_ƲRF_Oo Thank You! This is what I was looking for, you should post this as the answer! Also I think it should be $\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2}\rfloor$

Comment: @BlackEmperor it's really just a lot's of IBP

Answer (score 1):

Notice $$(2\pi ia)^{-2k}\left.\frac{d^{2k}}{dc^{2k}}\sin(2\pi ac x)\right|_{c=1}=x^{2k}\sin(2\pi a x),k\in \Bbb N$$

Therefore:

$$\int_{0}^{1}x^{2k}\sin(2\pi ax)dx= (2\pi ia)^{-2k}\left.\frac{d^{2k}}{dc^{2k}}\int_0^1\sin(2\pi ac x)dx\right|_{c=1} =\left.\frac{d^{2k}}{dc^{2k}}\frac{\sin^2(\pi a c)}{\pi a c(2\pi i a)^{2k}}\right|_{c=1}$$

Comment: Thank You for the answer! But this form will be difficult for me to use, as I need it as part of a bigger generalization problem.

Answer (score 1):

Youn can use this formula:
$$\int_0^1 x^n\sin(\alpha x)\mathrm{d}x=\frac{n!}{\alpha^{n+1}}\cos\left(\frac{\pi n}{2}\right)+\Im[E_{-n}(\alpha i)]\qquad\text{for }n\in\mathbb{N}$$

Where $E_{\nu}(z)$ is the generalized exponential function.
In particular:

$$E_{-n}(z)=n!e^{-z}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{z^{k-n-1}}{k!}$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I think this form might be difficult for me to use as I was trying to generalize,
$$\int_{0}^{1}x^m\lfloor tx\rfloor^ndx$$
for $m,n\in I_{x\geq0}$

Comment: That integral should be $0$ for all $m$ and $n$, since $\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor=0$ for $x\in[0,1]$. You are literally multiplying a power by 0. Are you sure the n shouldn't be inside the floor function?

Comment: My bad I missed a parameter there.

Comment: Ah okok, now it makes sense

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $n$ is a non negative integer and $a >0$

$$\int x^n\,e^{2 i \pi  a x}\,dx=(-i)^{1-n} \frac{\Gamma (n+1,-2 i a \pi  x)}{(2 a \pi)^{n+1}}$$ The problem is that, for the definite integral, the result is the sum of two generalized hypergeomatric functions and then
$$I_n(a)=\int_{0}^{1}x^n\sin(2\pi ax)\,dx$$ $$\large\color{blue}{I_n(a)=\frac{2 \pi  a}{n+2}\,\, _1F_2\left(\frac{n+2}{2};\frac{3}{2},\frac{n+4}{2};-a^2\pi ^2 \right)}$$

Let $2a\pi=t$

$$I_n(t)=\frac{t}{n+2}\,\, _1F_2\left(\frac{n+2}{2};\frac{3}{2},\frac{n+4}{2};-\frac {t^2}4\right)$$and $$t^{n+1}\,I_n(t)=A_n+ B_n\,\cos(t)+C_n\,\sin(t)$$ the first coefficients being
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
n & A_n & B_n & C_n \\
 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & -t & 1 \\
 2 & -2 & 2-t^2 & 2 t \\
 3 & 0 & -t \left(t^2-6\right) & 3 \left(t^2-2\right) \\
 4 & 24 & -t^4+12 t^2-24 & 4 t \left(t^2-6\right) \\
 5 & 0 & -t \left(t^4-20 t^2+120\right) & 5 \left(t^4-12
   t^2+24\right) \\
 6 & -720 & -t^6+30 t^4-360 t^2+720 & 6 t \left(t^4-20
   t^2+120\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Now, if $a$ is an integer, then

$$I_n(a)=\frac {A_n+B_n}{t^{n+1}}=\frac {D_n}{t^{n+1}} \qquad \text{where} \qquad t=2a\pi$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & D_n \\
 0 & 0 \\
 1 & -t \\
 2 & -t^2 \\
 3 & -t \left(t^2-6\right) \\
 4 & -t^2 \left(t^2-12\right) \\
 5 & -t \left(t^4-20 t^2+120\right) \\
 6 & -t^2 \left(t^4-30 t^2+360\right) \\
 7 & -t \left(t^6-42 t^4+840 t^2-5040\right) \\
 8 & -t^2 \left(t^6-56 t^4+1680 t^2-20160\right) \\
 9 & -t \left(t^8-72 t^6+3024 t^4-60480 t^2+362880\right) \\
 10 & -t^2 \left(t^8-90 t^6+5040 t^4-151200 t^2+1814400\right)
   \\
\end{array}
\right)$$